# Chisel 2 -- test harness for BlackBox -- how to integrate Verilog in simulator?

Tags: riscv, chisel

We are trying to use the Chisel BlackBox construct in Chisel 2.  Everything works fine, except when we try to test behavior.

The issue with the Blackboxing in Chisel2 is simulation with the C backend.

In Chisel3 we can point Chisel to the Verilog source and it has Verilator generate the C++ code and integrates it automatically.  In Chisel2, it doesn't use Verilator.  Instead, it generates C++ directly from the Chisel code.  So Chisel 2 doesn't generate C++ behavior for the Verilog that's inside the BlackBox.

What we tried is to use Verilator by hand to generate C++ from the Verilog code.  But we haven't figured out how to integrate that C++ with the C++ that Chisel 2 generates.  The issue is that every time we invoke sbt it regenerates the c++ code so all manual modifications get lost.

We also looked into porting c++ code in to Scala but it looks like we would have to port the c++ model of our verilog RTL through JNI (Java Native Interface) in order to run the simulation.

Does anyone have a viable solution for integrating the C++ code generated by Chisel 2 with C++ code generated from the verilog that is inside a Chisel Black Box?